# How to find an item in a dict with nested classes?

Tags: python

I'm a newbie programming in python and I can´t find a element in a complex dict (for me at least).

This dict contains items "FareAttribute" and the same time this class contains elements "FareRule". I want to find the element that matches FareRule.origin_id=="city1" and FareRule.destination_id=="city2".

How I can to find this?

Thanks for any comment in advance. I'm a bit lost

Edit to add dict (output when print first item). The classes belongs to transitfeed library (Google Transit). Right now I can't execute program, I'm out.

```
{u'AA': <FareAttribute [('currency_type', u'EUR'), ('fare_id', u'AA'), ('payment_method', 0), ('price', 1.5), ('rules', [<FareRule [('contains_id', None), ('destination_id', u'A'), ('fare_id', u'AA'), ('origin_id', u'A'), ('route_id', None)]>]), ('transfer_duration', None), ('transfers', 0)]>,...}
```

Comment: Please add the dict and also what you have attempted.

Comment: Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you post the dict itself? So I can take a look at the structure of the dict

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Excuse me all! I edited question and I hope its enough

Comment: @ccf If I write this:

    fare = filter(lambda x: x.fare_id == 'AA', self.schedule.GetFareAttributeList())[0].rules[0]
    print fare.origin_id, "-", fare.destination_id

I get the cities that I want. About your question, I think that a class instance (of both) is created when I create the 'schedule'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT2** Please try something like this (if python 2.7):

```
for fare in schedule.GetFareAttributeList():
    for rule in fare.GetFareRuleList():
        if rule.origin_id == 'B1' and rule.destination_id == 'B1':
            print rule
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if I try create dt object with all elements return syntax error.
And if I try with function to get entire dict return syntax error too.

    `code>>> print [k, v for k,v in schedule.GetFareAttributeList().items() if v.rules[0].origin_id == 'B1' and v.rules[0].destination_id == 'B1' ]
    File "<stdin>", line 1
    print [k, v for k,v in schedule.GetFareAttributeList().items() if v.rules[0].origin_id == 'B1' and v.rules[0].destination_id == 'B1' ]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: All right!!! Thank you so much. Your code works like a charm. Eternally grateful